# Issue installing puppet agent on Windows Servers

Tags: windows, puppet, puppet-agent

I'm trying to setup a Puppet dev environment in my datacenter. I've configured the Puppet Master on Cent0S 7 along with two agents, also running RH CentOS 7. The Puppet version I am running on the systems is Open Source Puppet 7.3. When I try to install the agent on a Windows Servers either 2012R2 or 2019 I get the error " Error: Could not download CA certificate: Bad Request". Both windows 2012R2 and Windows 2019 are "fresh installs." I've checked the puppet.conf file on both of the agents (windows boxes) and they’re correct. Both systems have the FQDN of my Puppet Master. The command(s) I'm using to gen the cert is "Puppet Agent -t”... and ... “Puppet SSL bootstrap”. I get the same error with both commands.  I’m able to resolve both of the windows computers on the PMaster and I'm able to resolve the PMaster on both of the computers. The Linux agents are able to communicate with the PMaster without a problem. I’ve tried both versions of the windows agent. Version 7.10_x64 and 7.00_x64.  Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue. The Windows servers are not allowing traffic on the puppet port most likely (8140 by default)